# lftp can connect, cd, but not ls, or mirror

Tags: shell, lftp

I'm trying to transfer files away from a Yahoo business hosting account using lftp. I can successfully connect and cd through the directories, but if I try data connection related commands (ls, mirror, etc), it times out with a socket related error. Below is the connection I'm using.

```
> lftp -d
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-protect-list yes
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-protect-data yes
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-auth TLS
lftp :~> set ssl:verify-certificate no
lftp :~> connect ftp.siteurl.com
lftp ftp.siteurl.com:~> login user@siteurl.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You should turn on debug to see what's going on with the data connection. Use command `debug`.

Most probable reason for the problem is a NAT router or a firewall. You can try to disable SSL or reverse `ftp:passive-mode` setting.

Comment: 'set ftp:passsive-mode off' work for me. Thanks!